Does this system involving blackbody radiation violate the second law of thermodynamics?
Consider the surface of rotation shown in heavy lines in the accompanying sketch. It is made up of parts of the surfaces of two confocal ellipsoids of revolution, and that of a sphere. The inside surface is a perfect mirror. The foci are labeled A and B. If two black bodies of equal temperature are initially placed at A and B, then all the radiation from A will reach B, but not vice versa, because radiation from B hitting the spherical surface will be reflected back. Therefore the temperature of B will increase spontaneously, while that of A will decrease spontaneously, and this would violate the second law.
Is the argument correct? Is it true for physical black bodies? Does the second law of thermodynamics still hold for radiation?


No, your entire cavity will attain a single temperature that is consistent with black body radiation. Even just by having two different confocal ellipsoids, the radiation will cease to only reach the foci, leading to spreading out.

@naturallyInconsistent What if there is a vacuum in the cavity?Then the temperature of the cavity isn't even well defined.

It doesnt matter. The "vacuum" inside the cavity is just going to be a photon gas.

The energy transfer in both directions is equal due to the conservation of etendue

“The law that entropy always increases—the Second Law of Thermodynamics—holds, I think, the supreme position among the laws of Nature. If someone points out to you that your pet theory of the universe is in disagreement with Maxwell’s equations—then so much the worse for Maxwell’s equations. If it is found to be contradicted by observation—well these experimentalists do bungle things sometimes. But if your theory is found to be against the second law of thermodynamics I can give you no hope; there is nothing for it but to collapse in deepest humiliation.” -Sir Arthur Eddington

Helmholtz reciprocity! If a light ray can go from A to B it can also go from B to A.

The resolution to this popular question is discussed specifically in Landberg's "A fallacy in the second law of thermodynamics?" and Yoder and Adkins, "Resolution of the ellipsoid paradox in thermodynamics"; see also the references within, which go back to at least 1864 ("On the concentration
of rays of light and heat and on the limits of its action")!

This is a neat problem!
If the temperature of B increased due to radiation from A, you would be able to build a perpetual motion machine of the first kind. Perhaps this is your objective? Unfortunately this will not work. As pointed out in comments it violates the first and second laws of thermodynamics.
NOTE: Without doing an exhaustive analysis, your assumptions are incorrect:
"all the radiation from A will reach B, but not vice versa"

Not all the energy from A is absorbed by B.

In this amended diagram you can see that much of the radiation from A does not travel directly to B through reflection from the two confocal ellipsoids of rotation. Some will be reabsorbed by A and some will strike the other ellipsoid of rotation in such a manner as to NOT be reflected to B.
If you want to prove your point, you need to do a further analysis of the actual radiative paths and the energy absorbed and emitted by the two black bodies.

I'm afraid you will find that this is not possible.
